# Why is my collectionView nil when using a delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a TableView containing 2 CollectionViews, each one in one of the TableViewCells. When I select an item in the first CollectionView, I want to update the second CollectionView. I am using a delegate pattern, but it doesn't work because my second CollectionView seems to be nil when I want use the .reloadData method, but why and how can I achieve updating the second CollectionView when selecting an item in the first CollectionView?

```
protocol TableViewCellDelegate {
func update()}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
var delegate: TableViewCellDelegate?

//...
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.delegate = ExistingInterestsCell() as? TableViewCellDelegate
        delegate?.update()}}


class ExistingInterestsCell: UITableViewCell, TableViewCellDelegate {
func update() {
    collectionView.reloadData()
}}
```

The error message is:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file Suggest_Accounts_and_Docs/ExistingInterestsCell.swift, line 13

Comment: Try to convert the code into readable format, it's hard to understand what is the issue here.

Comment: I am sorry but this is the best I could come up with, stack overflow seems to not see my code blocks so I have to add them 5 times by clicking the code icon, as soon as I use my return the code block ends, very weird maybe I am doing it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the wrong way to use the protocol / delegate pattern. You're creating classes that are too dependent on each other.

A better approach is to have your first row ***tell the controller*** that one of its collection view cells was selected, then allow the controller to update the data used for the second row, and then reload that row.

So, your "first row" cell will have this:

```
class FirstRowTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    var didSelectClosure: ((Int) -> ())?
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    // cell setup, collection view setup, etc...
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // tell the controller that a collection view cell was selected
        didSelectClosure?(indexPath.item)
    }

}
```

Your "second row" cell will have this:

```
class SecondRowTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var activeData: [String] = []
    
    // cell setup, collection view setup, etc...
    
}
```

In your table view controller, you'll have a var such as:

```
var dataType: Int = 0
```

and your `cellForRowAt` will look something like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstRowCell", for: indexPath) as! FirstRowTableViewCell

        // set the closure so the first row can tell us one of its
        //  collection view cells was selected
        c.didSelectClosure = { [weak self] i in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            // only reload if different cell was selected
            if i != self.dataType {
                self.dataType = i
                self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
            }
        }
        return c
    }

    let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "secondRowCell", for: indexPath) as! SecondRowTableViewCell
    switch dataType {
    case 1:
        c.activeData = numberData
    case 2:
        c.activeData = wordData
    default:
        c.activeData = letterData
    }
    c.collectionView.reloadData()
    return c
}
```

Here is a complete example...

**First Row Table Cell**

```
class FirstRowTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    var didSelectClosure: ((Int) -> ())?
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    let myData: [String] = [
        "Letters", "Numbers", "Words",
    ]
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        let fl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        fl.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        fl.minimumInteritemSpacing = 8
        fl.minimumLineSpacing = 8
        fl.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 80.0, height: 60)
        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: fl)
        
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        contentView.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        // to avoid auto-layout warnings
        let hConstraint = collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0)
        hConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
            hConstraint,
        ])
        
        collectionView.register(SingleLabelCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SingleLabelCollectionViewCell
        c.theLabel.text = myData[indexPath.item]
        return c
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // tell the controller that a collection view cell was selected
        didSelectClosure?(indexPath.item)
    }

}
```

**Second Row Table Cell**

```
class SecondRowTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var activeData: [String] = []
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        let fl = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        fl.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        fl.minimumInteritemSpacing = 8
        fl.minimumLineSpacing = 8
        fl.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 80.0, height: 60)
        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: fl)
        
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        contentView.addSubview(collectionView)
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        // to avoid auto-layout warnings
        let hConstraint = collectionView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0)
        hConstraint.priority = .defaultHigh
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
            hConstraint,
        ])
        
        collectionView.register(SingleLabelCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return activeData.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let c = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SingleLabelCollectionViewCell
        c.theLabel.text = activeData[indexPath.item]
        return c
    }
    
}
```

**Table View Controller**

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    let numberData: [String] = [
        "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15",
    ]
    let letterData: [String] = [
        "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O",
    ]
    let wordData: [String] = [
        "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth",
    ]

    var dataType: Int = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.register(FirstRowTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "firstRowCell")
        tableView.register(SecondRowTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "secondRowCell")
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstRowCell", for: indexPath) as! FirstRowTableViewCell

            // set the closure so the first row can tell us one of its
            //  collection view cells was selected
            c.didSelectClosure = { [weak self] i in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                // only reload if different cell was selected
                if i != self.dataType {
                    self.dataType = i
                    self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
                }
            }
            return c
        }

        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "secondRowCell", for: indexPath) as! SecondRowTableViewCell
        switch dataType {
        case 1:
            c.activeData = numberData
        case 2:
            c.activeData = wordData
        default:
            c.activeData = letterData
        }
        c.collectionView.reloadData()
        return c
    }
    
}
```

**Collection View Cell (used by both rows)**

```
// simple single-label collection view cell
class SingleLabelCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let theLabel = UILabel()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(theLabel)
        
        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            theLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        theLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
        contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    }
    
}
```

The result:

[image]

tap on "Numbers" and we see:

[image]

tap on "Words" and we see:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
self.delegate = ExistingInterestsCell() as? TableViewCellDelegate
```

refers to a table cell with nil outlets , that's why it's crashes , you need to access a real presented one

**Edit:** Add a reference to your tableView inside both cell classes, and using the indexPath and the table get the needed cell and update it's collection

```
if let cell = table.cellForRow(at:Indexpath(row:0,section:0)) as? ExistingInterestsCell {
  // update model
  cell.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I just didn't include the outlet since my code is very long, but the class ExistingInterestsCell contains an outlet: @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!, but why does it not work, or how do I access the real presented one?

Comment: `ExistingInterestsCell()` means `ExistingInterestsCell.init()` But it doesn't mean that's the one you see in screen? Question is which tableViewCell should be the delegate?

Comment: How do you present the 2 different cells ? in what order ?

Comment: The cell is on the screen, I can see both. ExistingInterestsCell is the delegate which has to be updated by using the .didSelectItem function of the "TableViewCell" class.

Comment: ExistingInterestsCell is in section 0 row 0 of the tableview, TableViewCell is in section 1 row 0 of the TableView.

Comment: Thank you, but what should be my self.delegate = .. be then? Also, I added my delegate variable to my question.

Comment: you can't link 2 cells of a table by a delegate because of dequeue process use above code to access a cell of table from another cell

Comment: I didn't know that! So my delegate should be the class containing the TableView right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226984/discussion-between-yokurt-and-sh-khan).